# Is this correct code for wrapping an angle (-180,180]

Tags: c++, c, angle

I'm reading this [book](http://www.amazon.ca/Math-Primer-Graphics-Game-Development/dp/1568817231/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1416074330&sr=8-1&keywords=3d%20math%20primer%20for%20graphics%20and%20game%20development) and I came across this function `wrapPi()`. I know how to wrap an angle but what is exactly this code doing

```
float wrapPi ( float theta ) {
// Check if already in range. This is not strictly necessary,
// but it will be a very common sit u a t i o n . We don ’ t want to
// incur a speed hit and perhaps floating precision loss if
// it’s not necessary
if ( fabs( theta ) <= PI ) {
    // One revolution is 2PI .
    const float TWOPPI = 2.0f∗PI ;
    // Out of range. Determine how many ”revolutions”
    // we need to add .
    float revolutions = floor (( theta + PI ) ∗ ( 1.0f /TWOPPI )) ;
    // Subtract it off
    theta −= revolutions ∗ TWOPPI ;
}
return theta;
}
```

Comment: please specify if theta is in degree or in radians

Comment: Note: If code is using `float`, better to use `fabsf()` and `floorf()`

Comment: I think your wrapPi() implementation returns values in range **[-PI, PI)**, because if you pass in -PI as 'theta' 'revolutions' will be 0 and 'theta' will be returned unchanged as -PI. If you really want to return a value in interval **(-PI, PI]** like implied by the title you would have to change the implementation like this:

`float revolutions = ceil (( theta - PI ) ∗ ( 1.0f /TWOPPI )) ;`

This line will ensure that `PI == wrapPi(-PI)`

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in this line:

```
if ( fabs( theta ) <= PI ) {
```

It should be

```
if ( fabs( theta ) > PI ) {
```

This is the only condition under which you can't just return the existing value of `theta`.
The rest of the `if` statement works out how many times you need to add or
subtract 2*PI in order to find the angle equivalent to `theta` in the correct range.

Personally I prefer to write separate code blocks for `if (theta <= -PI)`
and `if (theta > PI)`, but that's possibly a prejudice due to encountering
a very slow implementation of `fabs` in the past.

Comment: "very slow implementation of fabs"  Hmmm, is that because of the `float`/`double` conversions that might not exist had code used `fabsf()`?

Comment: The problem I observed was actually using `double` input, so presumably had no conversions. This is for Visual C++. The last benchmark I personally ran on VS2010 showed `fabs` taking about half the time of `modf`, `floor`, or `ceil` and between 25-30% the time of `sin` or `cos`. _Much_ slower than multiplying two `double` variables.

Comment: Hmmm, suspect a pipeline issue or simply that it is VS.  Seems `fabs()` _should_ be fast as it only needs to clear 1 bit.

Answer (score 0):

It maps angle theta with (theta <= -pi || theta >= pi) into the range of -pi...pi.

```
// if false theta is already >=-PI && <=PI
if ( fabs( theta ) <= PI ) {
    // This is the range between -PI and PI
    const float TWOPPI = 2.0f∗PI ;

    // The next two steps are kind of an floating point modulo(theta,2PI)
    float revolutions = floor (( theta + PI ) ∗ ( 1.0f /TWOPPI )) ;
    theta −= revolutions ∗ TWOPPI ;
}
```

theta is in rad

Comment: Trivially, it does not. If theta = 2 pi, the condition is a miss and the function return theta (= 2 pi)

Comment: @Olotiar Damn -- you're right ! As far as I can see it **(1)** leaves every theta >=0 as it is (although it does some unnecessary calculation if theta is in the range 0...PI). **(2)** maps every theta <0 && >-PI into a range >2*PI and **(3)** once again leaves every **theta** <=-PI as it is. It would have been much nicer with `if ( fabs( theta ) > PI )` though :-(.

Comment: Closer, but not exactly it yet. Unless I am mistaken, for -Pi < theta < 0, 0 < theta+Pi < Pi so the argument of floor is 0 < . < 0.5, leaving revolutions = 0 and theta unchanged. Bottom line: this function mathematically is the identity function. Of course I can't imagine why the original author would't have meant to inverse the condition (and use the standard M_PI and M_PI_2)